# Gap, void or vacuum?

Tags: british-english

I'm not sure how to distinguish these three words, they all have in common to fill something empty or missing. Are they interchangeable, or are they used in different contexts?

Comment: If you look up the definitions of these three words, you will find that gap is easily distinguished from void and vacuum.  If you then put the definitions of void and vacuum in your question with an illustrative sentence for each, you will have a question that shows some research.

Answer (score 1):

[gap](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gap):

> 1. A break or hole in an object or between two objects.
> 2. A space or interval; a break in continuity.

*Gap* can be used in situations when something is *missing* in a sequence of objects. It designates a place where something was supposed to be placed to fit with its surroundings, but there is nothing.

In contrast, *void* and *vacuum* describe a place containing *nothing*, regardless of its surroundings.

[void](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/void):

> 1. A completely empty space.
>    1.1 An unfilled space in a wall, building, or other structure.
>    1.2 An emptiness caused by the loss of something.

[vacuum](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vacuum):

> 1. A space entirely devoid of matter.
>    1.1 A space or container from which the air has been completely or partly removed.
>    1.2 A gap left by the loss, death, or departure of someone or something significant.

Considering their primary meanings, *vacuum* is used more often in a scientific context, in which case it means space completely or partially absent of any matter/air. It is a scientific term, while void can be used non-technically in a more abstract sense, but it can also be used when talking about empty space in a non-scientific way.